# Vuetify Error generated on existant project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to download vuetify 3 on my vue 3 app and it's giving me this error. I've tried the npm install --save @popperjs/core vuetify/styles but it doesn't work.
I'd like to know what's the reason behind this I know its still in beta but it should be stable.

> Failed to compile with 2 errors
>
> These dependencies were not found:
>
> - @popperjs/core in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js
> - vuetify/styles in ./src/plugins/vuetify.js
>
> To install them, you can run: npm install --save @popperjs/core vuetify/styles
> Error from chokidar (C:): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
> Terminer le programme de commandes (O/N) ? O

```sh
npm install --save @popperjs/core vuetify/styles
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/vuetify/styles.git
npm ERR! git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-28T19_25_57_260Z-debug-0.log
```

Answer (score 2):

`vuetify/styles` is not an NPM package, so don't try to install that. `vuetify` is the package name, and `styles` is contained in `vuetify`.

To install Vuetify 3 in a Vite project:

1. Install [`vuetify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetify/v/3.0.0-beta.0) 3.x (currently in the `next` tag):

   ```sh
   npm i -S vuetify@next
   ```
2. Install [`@vuetify/vite-plugin`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vuetify/vite-plugin) as a dev dependency:

   ```sh
   npm i -D @vuetify/vite-plugin
   ```
3. Configure Vite to use the plugin above:

   ```js
   // vite.config.js
   import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
   import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
   import vuetify from '@vuetify/vite-plugin' 

   export default defineConfig({
     plugins: [
       vue(),
       vuetify() 
     ],
   })
   ```
4. Create a Vuetify plugin instance, and install it in your Vue app:

   ```js
   // plugins/vuetify.js
   import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
   import 'vuetify/styles'

   export default createVuetify()
   ```

   ```js
   // main.js
   import { createApp } from 'vue'
   import App from './App.vue'
   import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

   createApp(App)
     .use(vuetify) 
     .mount('#app')
   ```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vuetify-starter?file=src%2FApp.vue)

Comment: I did all you said , it was loading the dev server , got to 98 % then stopped and I got the same error

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction?

Comment: A link to StackBlitz or Codesandbox that demonstrates the problem. A GitHub repo would do as well. See [mcve].

Comment: the code is actually really big, we're talking about 6000 lines of code :/

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without a way to reproduce the problem. You likely have the code in source control (GitHub). Can you share a link to that repo?